# Linear referencing - Make Route event layer: wrong spacing of points along route?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I want to simulate the ArcGis tool [Generate points along line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generate-points-along-lines.htm) with linear referencing tools (we don't have the licence for the former).

Our methodology is to

- create/use a line
- create an excel table with m-values (or the distance from the origin of the line) (see example below)
- For our problem, we want **equally spaced** distances between the points
- create a route from the line
- Use the [Make Route event layer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/make-route-event-layer.htm) to match the m-values to the route in order to create our "points along the line"

The problem is, that any time there is a bend in the line, the spacing of points is wrong (the gap is too large)

See 2 examples below, the right line is our actual business case, the left one I created myself to do a sanity check (digitized the line myself). On the left example you can clearly see that the problem occurs at every bend.

[image]

Below you can see the excel file we use to specify the point spacing:

[image]

This is the attribute table of the line on the left:
[image]

Tool parameters we used:
[image]

And the parameters used in the Create Route tool
[image]

Comment: It seems that at the bends of the line, 2 points are actually generated, see screenshot: https://imgur.com/aG8z13A

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: i was working in a geographic coordinate system (degrees on map). When changed to Projected coordinate system (meters on map), the points were nicely spread out evenly...

[image]